# Bundle Install on dev giving an error that a production gem is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-mavericks

Why is my gemfile not skipping over "production" gems?

I just installed Rails on Mac OS X Mavericks (possibly an irrelevant detail). When I do `bundle install`, it gives me an error about missing `pg` gem. However this is only listed in my `production` environment, so shouldn't it be skipped? Commenting out my `gem pg` makes `bundle install` successful. 
Extra context:

I just installed Rails on Mac OS X Mavericks. When I try to open my project, it seems to think I'm in "production" and tries to use my "pg" gem for Postgres. If I try to use `rails s` or `rails console`, I get the error that I haven't installed "pg" which should only be used in production for my DB.

I followed this tutorial: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.1.0.rc'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
# generates names, email addresses, and other placeholders for factories.
gem 'faker'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'aws-sdk', '1.11.1'
gem 'd3-rails', '~>3.3.7'
# used for file ajax uploads
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
# used for making server side variables accessible in JS

gem 'gon', '4.1.1'
gem "introjs-rails"
# High voltage for static pages
gem 'high_voltage', '~> 2.0.0'
gem "koala", "~> 1.8.0rc1"
gem 'acts_as_list'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  # rspec-rails includes RSpec itself in a wrapper to make it play nicely with Rails.
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # replaces Rails' default fixtures for feeding test data to the test suite with much more preferable factories
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  # watches your application and tests and runs specs for you automatically when it detects changes.
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # makes it easy to programatically simulate your users' interactions with your application
    gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec' # tims tutorial
  # opens your default web browser upon failed integration specs to show you what your application is rendering.
  gem 'launchy' # tims tutorial
  # helps clear out db after using selenium in tests
  gem 'database_cleaner' # tims tutorial
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
# added for resizing panes on d3fiddle pages
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# added for code highlighting on d3fiddle pages
gem 'codemirror-rails'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Bundler includes all groups. You have to explicitly exclude any groups you don't want like so:

`bundle install --without production`

After the first time, Bundler will remember your previous setting, so the `production` group will be excluded next time you run `bundle install`.